# problem refreshing div containing php code using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have read 3 posts on SO about how to do this, but its not working for some reason.

On the page index.php, i have this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function update() {
  $.get("index.php", function(data) {
    $("#uploadcount").html(data);
    window.setTimeout(update, 5000);
  });
}

</script>
```

and then this div, also in index.php

```
<div id=uploadcount>
<?
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mydb");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo "<h1>$num_rows</h1><h2>rows</h2>";
?>
</div>
```

The php is displaying the row count fine, but it wont refresh the number.
(i have latest jquery build included in head of index.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a solution that works great

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
setInterval(function()
{
     $('#uploadcount').fadeOut("fast").load('uploadcount.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000);

});
</script>


<div id="uploadcount">
<? include("uploadcount.php");?>
</div>
```

Thanks all to helped.

Answer (score 1):

Try enclosing your div ID in double quotes:

```
<div id="uploadcount">
```

Also, put your jQuery within a document.ready block, and the call to setTimeout should not be inside the $.get method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    function update() {
      $.get("index.php", function(data) {
        $("#uploadcount").html(data);
      });
    }
    window.setTimeout(update, 5000);
});
</script>
```

If you want to selectively retrieve something from a document, you can use [$.load](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load) with a selector, e.g.:

```
$("#uploadcount").load("index.php #uploadcount");
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load

That only works with jQuery 1.2 and above.

Comment: no effect. When i refresh the page i see changes, but nothing live.

Comment: ok that works, but when it refreshes, its loading the entire page. Should i store my php in a plain file with no other data and then include that file in index.php?

Comment: @Patrick - you will need to output only the HTML you want to insert, by whichever means best fits your application (I would normally use a function). I will make one last edit.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this for your update function

```
function update() {
    $("#uploadcount").load("index.php #uploadcount")
    window.setTimeout(update, 5000);
}
```